# navigate to <code>button</code> from <code>.li</code>

Tags: javascript, html, dom, navigation, parent-child

I am not able to reach to  `button`  tag from `.li`. How do I do it in JS?

```
    <div class="li">
        <li> Apple <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li> Ball <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li> Cat <button>Delete</button></li>
        <li> Dog <button>Delete</button></li>
    </div>
```

Is `button` a sibling or a child element of `li` tag? I get `undefined` in the console either way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to query the parent div first, then get all buttons

```
let buttons = document.body.querySelector(".li").getElementsByTagName("button");

// test if we've queried the buttons successfully 
buttons[0].style.display = "none";
```